# Notice: Undefined variable: list_livro

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

```
    <form class="form" method="POST"action="processa_livro.php">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>Autor</th>
                            <th>Categoria</th>
                            <th>Ação</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="myTable">
                        <?php echo "<tr>"?>
                            <?php echo"<td>". $list_livro['nome']."</td>"?>
                            <?php echo"<td>". $list_livro['autor']."</td>"?>
                            <?php echo"<td>". $list_livro['categoria']."</td>"?>
                            <td>
                            <input type="image" name="submit" src="img/alter.png" value="alterar" style="width:20px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="image" name="submit" src="img/deletar.png" value="deletar" style="width:20px;">
                            </td>
                        <?php echo"</tr>"?>
  </table>
</form>
```

**processa_livro.php**

```
<?php
include_once("conexao.php");

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$autor = $_POST['autor'];
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];

$sql = "insert into livro (nome, autor, categoria) values ('$nome', '$autor','$categoria')";
$cadastrar = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);


$list = "SELECT nome, autor, categoria FROM livro";
$list_livro = mysqli_query($conexao, $list);
mysqli_close($conexao);

?>
```

Estou tendo essa saída. Alguém poderia indicar o caminho para que eu possa estar arrumando?

Comment: Dentro do corpo da sua tabela você tenta exibir dados de uma variável `$list_livro` que não está definida.

Comment: `$list_livro` só existe no arquivo `processa_livro.php`, você está importando o arquivo? tenta adicionar `<?php include_once('processa_livro.php') ?>` antes da tabela em html.

Comment: Eu inclui a variavel $list_livro em processa_livro.php. A partir disso ela não leria automaticamente?

Comment: @edsonalves Isso daria outros erros, pois o arquivo receberia uma requisição GET, mas trata apenas a requisição POST. Maick, não, são arquivos diferentes, com escopos diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Essa variável `$list_livro` só existe no arquivo processa_livro.php. Uma possível solução seria você colocar a consulta no arquivo que mostra a tabela. Como por exemplo:

```
<?php
    include_once("conexao.php");
    $list = "SELECT nome, autor, categoria FROM livro";
    $list_livro = mysqli_query($conexao, $list);
    mysqli_close($conexao);
?>

<form class="form" method="POST"action="processa_livro.php">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Autor</th>
            <th>Categoria</th>
            <th>Ação</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="myTable">
        <?php echo "<tr>"?>
            <?php echo"<td>". $list_livro['nome']."</td>"?>
            <?php echo"<td>". $list_livro['autor']."</td>"?>
            <?php echo"<td>". $list_livro['categoria']."</td>"?>
            <td>
            <input type="image" name="submit" src="img/alter.png" value="alterar" style="width:20px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="image" name="submit" src="img/deletar.png" value="deletar" style="width:20px;">
            </td>
        <?php echo"</tr>"?>
    </table>
</form>
```